# Is it possible to compute Bayes factors for correlations in R using multiply imputed datasets?

Tags: r, correlation, bayesian, r-mice

I am using multiply imputed datasets for my analysis (generated using `mice`). I wonder whether it is possible to calculate Bayes factors for the correlations? It should be added that I have both numerical variables and factors in my dataset.

I have tried using the `BayesFactor` package, function `correlationBF()`, but I think I may have the wrong version of R to use this. And also, it is meant for a single dataset, not pooling results from multiple datasets.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: This question mainly aims at trying to find a package or function that would enable the analysis, I can't seem to find any through searching.